# ASP.NET MVC 5: Client Validation is not working for a view model (annotations)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation, bundling-and-minification

I have the following scripts that existed in the project, its already bundled and rendered in the layout page:

[image]

Code in BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()    
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The index page uses the _layout, when pressing the add button, i am rendering partial view inside a div in the index page:

```js
function LaodDivToSave() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var div = $("#DivAppendPartialView");
        div.load('@Url.Action("Create", "Product")');      
    })
}
```

The Partial View "Create":

```
@model Lib.Models.Product
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorForModel()
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="CreateProduct()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The editor template

```
@model lib.Models.Product
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
</div
```

and finally the model class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide  name!")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "name is too long!")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide price!")]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Product price must be between 1 and 100!")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand, where should i put this function, also in the form loaded i don't have submit, because i am using ajax to post the values.

Comment: Read the dupe - you need to reparse the validator after the content is loaded - `div.load('@Url.Action("Create", "Product")', function(data) { // reparse the validator here});`